# open modal popup using asp:button vb web forms

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have an `<asp:button>` where I require it to execute an action and after that open a modal popup. I've searched several solutions but I can't find any that work correctly.

This is my button:

`<asp:Button ID="BtnCaptura" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="BtnCaptura_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary"/>`

I already tried making an html `<button>` and using the Onclick action to execute the method and open the modal, but I get an error when executing the ajax that redirects to that function.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are two use cases here.

We have a button, (server side), and we want to pop a dialog. This setup is common (and not quite your question - but we will get to that in a minute).

So, the first order of the day is to adopt some kind of dialog system. While I like the look + feel of the Bootstrap dialogs, they are hard to work with, and have few options to position the dialog.

So, I suggest using the jQuery.UI dialog. And that does suggest that you already using jQuery. (Most asp.net sites and their templates do include jQuery, and have done so for about 13 years or so).

So, let's do the first use case.

We have a button, and want to "confirm" that button. How this works is a asp.net button has two parts. A server side click event, and a client side click event. If the client-side event (JavaScript) returns true, then the server side (code behind) button code will run. If the client-side JavaScript returns false, then the server-side button (code behind) does not run.

So, say this simple GridView with a delete button, and an edit button.

I used an image button, but the code works the same for a regular asp.net button.

So, this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" Width="45%"
            DataKeyNames="ID" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="First Name"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Descripiton" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
                            ImageUrl="~/Content/trashcan1.png"
                            Width="48px"
                            Height="40px"
                            onclick="cmdDelete_Click"
                            OnClientClick="return mydelpop(this)"
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
            <div id="mypoparea" style="display:none">
                <h4>Delete this Hotel?</h4>
                <h4><i>(this can't be un-done)</i></h4>
            </div>

<script>
    var mydelok = false
    function mydelpop(btn) {

        if (mydelok) {
            mypopok = false
            return true
        }

        myDialog = $("#mypoparea")
        myDialog.dialog({
            title: "Delete Hotel",
            modal: true,
            sizable: true,
            width: '380',
            closeText: "",
            position: { my: 'right top', at: 'left bottom', of: btn },
            buttons: {
                Delete: function () {
                    myDialog.dialog('close')
                    mydelok = true
                    btn.click()
                },
                cancel: function () {
                    myDialog.dialog('close')
                }
            }
        })
        return false
    }
</script>
```

Note how our button (Image button) has two events. The server-side event, and then the OnClientClick event.

So, the code behind for this button is:

```
Protected Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim btn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblhotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    MyRstPE(cmdSQL)
    LoadGrid()    ' re-load grid update display

End Sub
```

So, when we run the above, we get this:

[image]

So, above shows how to pop a dialog BEFORE the server-side code runs, and if that dialog returns true, or false, it controls if the server-side button code will run.

Now, part two, and your question:

We want to click a server-side button, run some code, do whatever, AND THEN pop a client-side dialog.

So, let's add an Edit button to the above grid.

That button when clicked will:

Get GridView row, load some data into a div, (the one record), and the pop a dialog. Note that while we are using this for an edit, it could be for example some kind of additional confirm.

The ONLY issue to keep in mind is that code behind can't "halt" in the middle of the code. So, you often have to split out a server-side triggered dialog into two parts. The first code (server side) can setup and pop the dialog, but the confirmation then has to be based on another button click in which the whole process is completed.

So, let's add an edit button to the above GridView.

So, the two buttons markup looks like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
    ItemStyle-Width="140px"
    >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
            ImageUrl="~/Content/trashcan1.png"
            Width="48px"
            Height="40px"
            onclick="cmdDelete_Click"
            OnClientClick="return mydelpop(this)"
            />

        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdEdit" runat="server"
            ImageUrl="~/Content/edit2.png"
            Width="48px"
            Height="40px"
            onclick="cmdEdit_Click"
            style="margin-left:15px"
            />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So, we now drop in a div for editing the one record.

Say some markup in a div called "edit area".

So, say this:

(I'll not post all, since it just a div with some controls).

```
<div id="EditRecord" runat="server" style="display:none;padding:16px" clientidmode="Static"  >

    <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
            <label>HotelName</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" 
                runat="server" f="HOtelName" width="280"></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <label>First Name</label><asp:TextBox ID="tFN" 
                runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <label>Last Name</label><asp:TextBox ID="tLN" 
                runat="server" f="LastName" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <label>City</label><asp:TextBox ID="tCity" 
                runat="server" f="City" Width="140"></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <label>Province</label><asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" 
                runat="server" f="Province" Width="75"></asp:TextBox> <br />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px" class="iForm">
        <label>Description</label> <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="400" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Height="150px" f="Description" ></asp:TextBox> <br />
```

So, above is just a div with some controls, and we will use the jQuery.UI dialog to pop up above. Note how this cmdEdit button does NOT have a client-side event.

So, the code behind to do some things and THEN pop a dialog FROM that code behind looks like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim btn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)

    fLoader(EditRecord, rstData.Rows(0))  ' code to load div
    ' pop the dialog client side
    Dim sJava As String = $"myedit('{btn.ClientID}')"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "MyPop", sJava, True)


End Sub
```

And our client-side code above calls is this:

```
<script>
    function myedit(Sbtn) {
        var btn = $('#' + Sbtn)
        myDialog = $("#EditRecord")
        myDialog.dialog({
            title: "Edit Hotel",
            modal: true,
            sizable: true,
            width: '830',
            closeText: "",
            position: { my: 'right top', at: 'left bottom', of: btn }
        })
    }

</script>
```

And now the result is this:

[image]